# Pushing to github repo produces curl error 56

Tags: git, github, rpc

Just created a new repo, and on desktop I want to push the main branch to GitHub (theres around 40000 source code files). Every time I try this, I get

```
Enumerating objects: 46338, done.
Counting objects: 100% (46338/46338), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (41677/41677), done.
Writing objects: 100% (46338/46338), 706.90 MiB | 68.44 MiB/s, done.
Total 46338 (delta 5210), reused 43639 (delta 4240), pack-reused 0
error: RPC failed; curl 56 Send failure: Connection was aborted
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

Ive tried updating http post buffer, and paused the firewall and anti virus. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Your internet just disconnected. Try it with a better connection

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30956603)